# Countable "cable" versus uncountable "cable"

Tags: countable-nouns, countability, word-form

From [Merriam-Webster's Learner's Dictionary](http://learnersdictionary.com/definition/cable):

> [count] computer cables
>
> [noncount] We need more cable to hook up the computers.

What's the difference between the countable "cable" and the uncountable "cable"?

I never knew that "cable" can be uncountable because a cable is always in the shape of a string. So I don't understand why "cable" can be uncountable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can think of it as a material in the uncounable sense. You need more cable, more gold, more stone, etc. In that case, *cable*'s physical quantity is length, measured in, say, meters, or feet.

Comment: It appears to mean an unspecified amount, or at least a non standard amount. With cables you have a number of cables so you can have three cables or four. In the second example we have a generic value of "more" which is not that helpful but perhaps the details of how much cable will be needed don't need to be known at that point, just a note that cables will be needed later.

Comment: Actually, you're right that "cable" is like "string." The word "string" has both countable and uncountable definitions, just like "cable."

Answer (score 4):

It's only really uncountable when you're talking about its length. In most situations, it's countable.

> We need more cable to hook up the computers.

The cable isn't long enough, we need more of **it**.

<sup>Practically in this situation, you need a different, longer cable, but just for the sake of this exercise let's assume you will extend it by some method</sup>

> We need more cables to hook up the computers.

We need three cables, we only have two.

> Cable comes on 100m rolls, from which you can make up your own cables.
>
> Ready-made cables come in packs of six.